Get Private FQDNs, IPs, Names of the Private Endpoints for the Azure resources deployed in an Virtual Network using PowerShell Script
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxxx' -SubscriptionId 'xxxx'

# Get the Resource Group Name
$resourceGroupName = "city-app-rg-xx-uat"

# Get all Private Endpoints in the Resource Group
$privateEndpoints = Get-AzPrivateEndpoint -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

# Create a list to store the data
$data = @()

# Loop through each Private Endpoint
foreach ($privateEndpoint in $privateEndpoints) {
    $fqdn = $privateEndpoint.PrivateDnsZoneGroup.Name
    $ipAddresses = $privateEndpoint.PrivateIPAddresses -join ","
    $name = $privateEndpoint.Name

    $data += [PSCustomObject]@{
        FQDN = $fqdn
        IPAddress = $ipAddresses
        Name = $name
    }
}

# Export the data to a CSV file
$data | Export-Csv -Path "PrivateEndpointDetails.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Output received:

In the output, the Fully Qualified Domain Name (Private endpoint URL) and the Private IPs of the azure resources are not printed in the output file.
Unable to identify what is wrong in the above PowerShell script.

did you inspect the $privateEndpoints variables to see what returned?

yes, it is returning the resource group name, private endpoint name, location, provisioning state, subnet details in the $privateEndpoints.

Is it possible to get the private ip, fqdns of the private endpoints?

you would need to query other resources. like private ip will be linked to the network interface etc

Are you expecting the output to be like this?

HI @VenkatV, Yes. The same output I'm expecting

Can I post the answer with code?

yep, sure @VenkatV

HI @VenkatV, Are you providing your answer?

Hi @VivekAnandChakravarthy, I just posted an answer with code, Hope this helps to resolve your issue.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Get Private FQDNs, IPs, Names of the Private Endpoints for the Azure resources deployed in an Virtual Network using PowerShell Script

Here is the updated PowerShell script to fetch the private endpoint FQDN and Private IP address.
$dnsConfigData = @()

$privateEndpoints = Get-AzPrivateEndpoint -ResourceGroupName "Automation_RG"

foreach ($endpoint in $privateEndpoints) {
    if ($endpoint.CustomDnsConfigsText) {
        
        $dnsConfigs = $endpoint.CustomDnsConfigsText | ConvertFrom-Json
        foreach ($config in $dnsConfigs) {
           
            $PEfqdn = $config.Fqdn
            $PEipAddresses = $config.IpAddresses -join "," 

            
            $dnsConfigData += [pscustomobject]@{
                Fqdn        =  $PEfqdn
                IpAddresses = $PEipAddresses
            }
        }
    } else {
        Write-Output "No Custom DNS Configs found for this endpoint."
    }
}
$dnsConfigData | Export-Csv -Path "PrivateEndpointDnsdetails.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

Write-Output "CSV file created: PrivateEndpointDnsdetails.csv"

Output:

Excel Output


Will check the solution on Nov 5 6 PM

Still checking Venkat V, give me couple of hours time on tomorrow

Hi @VivekAnandChakravarthy, I hope you tried the solutions and they work for you?

I might not have exactly what your looking for but you can use this to get the information, you can then use it to scope it differently for your needs.
# Retrieve all private endpoints in the subscription
$privateEndpoints = Get-AzPrivateEndpoint

# Check if private endpoints exist
if ($privateEndpoints.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No private endpoints found in this subscription."
    exit
}

# Loop through each private endpoint and output information
foreach ($endpoint in $privateEndpoints) {
    Write-Output "Resource Group: $($endpoint.ResourceGroupName)"
    Write-Output "Private Endpoint Name: $($endpoint.Name)"

    # Initialize an array to store FQDNs
    $fqdnList = @()
    
    # Loop through private link service connections to build FQDNs
    foreach ($connection in $endpoint.PrivateLinkServiceConnections) {
        if ($connection.GroupIds -and $connection.GroupIds.Count -gt 0) {
            foreach ($group in $connection.GroupIds) {
                $fqdnList += "$($group).privatelink.$($connection.Name).azure.net"
            }
        }
    }

    # Display FQDNs or "None found" if empty
    if ($fqdnList.Count -gt 0) {
        Write-Output "FQDNs:"
        foreach ($fqdn in $fqdnList) {
            Write-Output "  - $fqdn"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Output "FQDNs: None found"
    }

    # Retrieve the private IP addresses from network interfaces
    Write-Output "IP Addresses:"
    $networkInterface = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceId $endpoint.NetworkInterfaces.Id

    # Loop through IP configurations to fetch private IP addresses
    $ipAddresses = $networkInterface.IpConfigurations | ForEach-Object { $_.PrivateIpAddress }
    
    if ($ipAddresses.Count -gt 0) {
        foreach ($ip in $ipAddresses) {
            Write-Output "  - $ip"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Output "  - None found"
    }

    Write-Output "-----------------------------------------"
}


Hi @TimmyMalmgren, with your code, I'm getting the private link URL of the private endpoint but not the customer visible fqdn. It means i'm getting the url like kv-hps-uat-uks-01.privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net instead of the normal fqdn kv-hps-uat-uks-01.vault.azure.net.
